# Is there a way to detect OS level scaling in a web app?

Tags: responsive-design, scaling

I have a situation where a client on a windows machine with a small screen has an OS level zoom set to 150%, this means their 1920x1080 laptop is effectively 1280x720 and usable height less than this due to browser chrome.

We've used media queries to detect the device-width, but I'm not clear on whether this is including or excluding the 150% zoom. I've not been able to confirm but it visually appears to be using the 1920px width queries.

Whilst I can find quite a lot on browser level zoom, my question: Is it possible to detect the OS level scaling within a webpage, and if so, where would I find it?